# Testing with Laravel two forms with the same input name

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I have two forms on the same page. These forms are the login and signup. They are located on Modals, that's the reason they are on the same page.

When testing with PHPUnit, I want to test the signup form so I'm doing:

```
$this->visit('/')
  ->click('Sign up')
  ->see('Already have an account?')
  ->type('test@email.com', 'email')
  ->type('password', 'password')
  ->type('password', 'password_confirmation')
  ->press('submit-sign-up')
```

The problem is that the input with name email is also present in Login Form.

I know that I could just change the input name, but I'm wondering if is there a way to test the input of signup form in any way.

Comment: You can check with the name of your form, or the name of your submit input.

Answer (score 0):

Researching I have found the answer to my question. There is a function call submitForm that allows you to specify which Form you are testing and then send an array of the inputs with its values:

```
protected function submitForm($buttonText, $inputs = [], $uploads = [])
```